# How to change default mobile-first approach(Tailwind) in desktop first?

Tags: css, responsive, tailwind-css

Is there any chance to change it or I must use mobile-first approach with Tailwind ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to your `tailwind.js` config file, look for the `screens` section. By default you will find the list of screen sizes like this: `'sm': '576px'`. Tailwind uses min-width by default, you can change those values to `'sm': {'max':'576px'}` to force max-width.

Comment: Tailwind uses "width" to define responsiveness and not height.

Answer (score 9):

Tailwind generates a corresponding max-* modifier for each breakpoint. For example:

```html
   <h1 class="text-green-500 max-md:text-red-500">Test</h1>
```

Here the green color will apply to all screen sizes and the red color will overwrite it only for screens that are smaller than the medium breakpoint (768px).

More info: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-a-breakpoint-range